# Run asp.net mvc project on the other computer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've created an asp.net mvc3 project with Visual Studio 2010. I want to know that all the menues and html properties will be seen in suitable positions or not. My monitor in 15-inch and I want to see my project in other computers with 13-inch or 17-inch. How can I run my project in a computer that Visual Studio, EF and ... have'nt installed on it?

Comment: The simplest thing for you may be to remote desktop into your machine from another one. That way you don't have to fuss with sharing your network or setting up IIS etc.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I think using something like screen sharing apps will show everything like my monitor with different scale but I want to know that menus,image slider and ... will be seen in correct positions or not

Comment: or open the port via any firewall you have that casini is using to your local network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm making the assumption that all of the computers are on the same network.  If they aren't this won't work (and realistically you're going to have to have a common network between them).

The easiest thing to do would be to make sure you've installed IIS on your development machine.

Next `deploy` your MVC application to the local IIS.  At that point it should be visible to the other machines on your network.

Here's an answer to a similar question that has plenty of links on how to set this up.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3632434/52136